# UIView stretching side instead of adjusting width & origin

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, transformation

This is probably an easy question, whether its possible or not i have no idea; but easy none the less.

```
Screen       = 0x   0y 1000w 1000h
UIView Start = 500x 0y 500w  1000h
UIView End   = 0x   0y 1000w 1000h
```

I have a UIView lets say covering the right side of the screen with the dimensions and coordinates above. Right now i know to get to the end point i have to do

```
CGRectMake(start.origin.x - 500, start.origin.y, start.size.width + 500, start.size.height)
```

Is it possible to just do something like

```
[uiview stretchLeftSide:500];
```

that way i do not need to touch the origin or width directly. it causes some issues as the view contains controls where i cannot manage there anchoring so they just jump to the specified location, then the view adjusts (this is all animated BTW).

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know relocating & resizing a `UIView` this way - `CGRectMake(start.origin.x - 500, start.origin.y, start.size.width + 500, start.size.height)` is the way to do it.

It's ugly but that's what I used to do. But you could inherit `UIView` and add a method `stretchLeftSide` and implement what you want. In longer running projects this makes absolute sense and should be done as a practice...

Comment: Thanks. How would i go about doing the actual strech ? because as i said i cannot modify anything other than the left side or the controls mess up, and i cannot think of a way to do it. Other than in a for loop or something so i move the view then add to the width little by little so that the controls dont jump. but i really dont want to do that.

Comment: or, just thinking about it, is it possible to set the anchor properties on uibarbuttonitems ? they are the ones giving issues.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm assuming your `UIView` (let's just call it view) is a subview of `Screen` (i.e. you did something like `[Screen addSubview:view]`).

If you want to do the animation so the left side stretches the way you want, basically, all you have to do is set the origin of `view` to `(0,0)` and the size to be the same as `Screen`. For this, you can use `Screen.bounds` which is exactly what you want the final frame of `view` to be. The `bounds` property of a view will always have an origin of `(0,0)` and a size equal to the size of the view.

If you have a reference to `Screen`, you can use `Screen.bounds` as I mentioned above, but if you don't, and you know that `view` is a subView of `Screen`, then you can use `view.superview.bounds`.

Now the animation. Because I have to write apps that support iOS versions as old as 3.0, I can't use block animations. Instead, I use `UIView` class methods like this:

```
// Here you can enter an identifier to identify your animation
// and an object that will be passed to your delegate. 
// These 2 parameters are only useful if you set an animation delegate 
// using [UIView setAnimationDelegate:delegate];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];  

// Duration in seconds    
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];  

// Perform you changes here.
view.frame = view.superview.bounds;

// Commit the changes
[UIView commitAnimations];
```